# Magento 2: How to show request variable in Layout file

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, dynamic

http://localhost/magento2/module/List/Variable

Here Variable is my dynamic value, which would like to show in Breadcrumb & Title via Layout File.

**app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\layout\module_list_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" display="true">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">e-Trade | List {request var goes here}</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">List</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">List</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{request var goes here}</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to use a variable in xml. It's a static format.

Comment: Thanks @AaronAllen. So what will be workaround?

Comment: You should build the logic into the block class. Blocks are where most of the dynamic content should be generated.